# error: "va_start" used in Win64 ABI funtion getting thi seero in clang help me to solve this?

Tags: c++, c, clang, covariance

I have compiled but while compiling with CLANG in ubuntu im getting error like this error: "va_start" used in Win64 ABI funtion. can anyone help me?

Comment: Whatever calling convention that is might not support varargs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function is `static` *and* I doubt you're passing it anywhere as an argument, I believe you can just remove `EFIABI` here (and in the declaration). `EFIABI` is a 4-register calling convention for which GCC seemingly does not support variable arguments.

Comment: Thnaks but I have tried by removing EFIABI but its not working.

Comment: And what happens *then*?

Comment: Then the compiler is set to have a *default calling convention* I guess

Comment: So, I guess you need to specify *another* calling convention here manually.

Comment: yeah in addition to this error i'm getting "error:SSE register return with SSE disabled".

Comment: Can you help in this too?

Answer (score 0):

`va_*` are explicitly ban by clang, per [here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-April/098578.html). Use the builtins if you want to "cross-compile" between linux and windows targets, per [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Is-it-a-va-arg-bug-in-clang-td4049311.html), also add `__attribute__((ms_abi))`, otherwise it will not work either, see [these tests](https://github.com/Microsoft/clang/blob/master/test/Sema/varargs-x86-64.c).

```
static int
__attribute__((ms_abi))
va_Utimes(
  const char   *path,
  ...
  )
{
  __builtin_ms_va_list ap;

  __builtin_ms_va_start(ap, path);
  retval = ...ioctl( filp, FIOSETIME, ap);
  __builtin_ms_va_end(ap);

  return retval;
}
```

Comment: yeah its working thank you.can you please help in this also "error:SSE register return with SSE disabled". on below line

Comment: double
difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0)
{
  return (double)(time1 - time0);
}

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)